# C# Property based on another property

Tags: c#, .net, api, properties, request

Below is given a small part of a request with two properties that depend on each other.

I need to make it so that :

If DisableMessages is sent and MessagesOn is not sent through the API, then default MessagesOn to false.

If DisableMessages is not sent and MessagesOn is not sent, then default DisableMessages to false and MessagesOn to true.

```
public class CreateRequest
{
    public bool DisableMessages { get; set; }

    public bool MessagesOn { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Disable Messages is sent" or "MessagesOn is sent"?

Comment: The above is a specification. What is your _question_? What specifically do you need help with? Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service. Please fix your post so that it includes a [mcve] showing exactly what you tried, along with a detailed explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want, and what it is that you can't figure out. See also [ask] for more advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: Agree with Peter, lacking a bit of context on what you're trying to achieve.  Also, seems that one input affects itself...so a bit confusing.  You may need another property that would be use boolean logic of both those properties.

Comment: II think by reading between the lines, one can understand what the op is asking for. Since the `CreateRequest` is a request and the tag is API.

Comment: When there are two Boolean inputs, there are four possible logic paths. You only specified the behavior for two.

Answer (score 2):

Use backing variables and nullable types. I'm leaving `MessagesOn` for you to set.

```
public class CreateRequest
{
    bool? disableMessages;
    bool? messagesOn;

    public bool? DisableMessages { 
        get { return this.disableMessages == null && messagesOn == null ? false : this.disableMessages;} 
        set { this.disableMessages = value;} }

    public bool? MessagesOn { get {return /* DisableMessages is sent and MessagesOn is not sent */;} set { this.messagesOn = value;} }
}
```